# Getting errors for sass-loader - angular2, bootstrap-loader, webpack 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack-2

My project is based on this nice repo - https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/tree/minimal. And I updated packages to angular **2.2.3**, webpack **2.1.0-beta.27** and bootstrap-loader **2.0.0-beta.16**. And when I try to build it I get these:

> > ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/resolve-url/resolve-url.js!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./src/app/shared/datepicker/datepicker.component.scss
> >     Module build failed: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Here's how I use SASS in my components:

`` @Component({
    selector: '...',
    template: `...`,
    providers: [],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: ["./datepicker.component.scss"]
}) ``

and the datepicker.component.scss file:

`@import "/node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css";`

Can someone explain what this error is please?

Answer (score 0):

try: `styles: require("./datepicker.component.scss")`

That way, a standard webpack configuration can scan for the required files and properly load and link them.